# PWA access site settings in standalone mode

Tags: javascript, html, web, progressive-web-apps

Is there a way for a PWA app in standalone mode that has permissions, say notifications permissions, denied by the user to be changed again? I know for regular websites, they just tap the padlock icon and can access site settings hence change whatever permissions they had granted or denied, but for a PWA, since there is no url bar, how is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way I know is to open the site in the browser on the device, and change the setting there - which kinda sux :p

Comment: I also had that idea but was wondering if there was another way, a better way

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about mobile right now. Nothing is apparent...

But on desktop you can.

[image]

Open the application menu from the 3 vertical dots

[image]

Then select site settings. This will open the web page where the user can change all the permissions, etc.

I will try this later, but I have a feeling you might be able to provide a link to the application/site setting URL in your applications. For example:

chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fyourdomain.com
or
edge://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fyourdomain.com

Not sure about Apple...I mean who is LOL

Comment: Hi chris any updates on opening installed PWA's setting (not bookmarklets) on android ? PS: love your blog, hope you update it more often

Comment: Thnx. I have been writing more on https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/ lately